# Can rep features have a lower requirement count?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation

Can you please lower the amount of rep requirements for us newer users? The rep requirement for some features (*cough* like downvotes and comments) shouldn't be so high. Thanks!

Comment: Why did you tag this question with the `swag` tag? What would you do with more power I wonder? -- anyway, I asked this a long time ago (in meta.so) and it was declined

Comment: @jmfsg Can't various Exchanges have their own rep requirements? Or is SO unique because it's "the main one"?

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh I wouldn't say it's impossible, but you'd need *really* good Arqade-specific reasons to change the reputation limits. I can think of at least one reason, but not for what concerns downvoting or commenting. (Note: moderators can't control reputation requirements.)

Comment: @badp Yeah, I wasn't necessarily saying it was a good idea, but was more curious if it was possible at all.

Comment: What need is being met by lowering the rep requirements?  You can already comment on your own questions and answers.  Downvoting is supposed to require at least a token contribution to the site, to ensure newcomers can't skew the community's opinions too greatly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are [three sets of privilege levels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared). The first (and lowest across the board) is what's used while the site is in private beta and most people don't have much reputation at all. Once the site moves to public beta, the thresholds are bumped up a bit. Once the sites graduate, the thresholds go up to what they are across the network.

Stack Overflow does have a few changes compared to other sites, but that's because it's so big that we actually had to *increase* the requirements for some of the privileges. "Create new tags", for example, requires 1500 rep on Stack Overflow vs 300 on any other graduated site. (Come to think of it, that might be the only one. But still, the precedent is there.) None of the privileges on Stack Overflow require *less* reputation than on other graduated sites.

We currently have no plans to adjust these lower thresholds, but if you have any specific arguments for doing so, by all means bring them up and we'll see what's what. For the moment, though, this is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Answer (score 8):

It really isn't hard to get post comments anywhere.  1 good question and 1 good answer (preferably accepted), and that could easily be 70 rep.  Get 200 rep on any site on the network, and suddenly, you get the 2 requested features across the board.  Well actually, you have to do a little more work to get downvote privileges, but it puts you really close.

We are probably one of the most up-vote happy site on the network -- if you post original, complete, and helpful answers, or interesting questions.  If you post weeks after another answer, and it's not truly ground breaking, you won't be upvoted.  If you don't defend your answer, either with sound arguments or solid sources, you won't be upvoted.

We reward hard work, which is why you'll see answers that are paragraphs long, even for questions that are barely a sentence.  Some might pound these answers out in 15 minutes, others will spend days editing and refining, but in both cases, a significant amount of effort was spent in researching and verifying their answers, either previously or when confronted with the problem.

So TL;DR: work hard for your rep, and it will come.  You're fairly new, and almost all of us were one time at the same stage as you.